# Linq в sql many-to-many

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

У меня есть таблица Employees и Skills, модели сделаны по принципу many-to-many отчего в бд создалось 3 таблицы, одна Employees, одна Skills и одна EmployeeSkill.

Теперь мне нужно сделать вроде банальную вещь, получить скилы относящиеся к конкретному Employee. Как это делается? Ведь в таблице Skills нет поля ElpoyeeId - так было бы, если бы отношение было один ко многим, а у меня нет такого поля. У меня в Skills поля: Id, Name. В Employees: Id, Name, SecondName, BirthDate, Salary, VacansyId. А про скилы там речи нет. Зато в табилце EmployeeSkill прописаны эти отношения: EmployeeId and SkillId.

Всё было бы просто если бы у меня была в приложении такая модель, чтобы я мог в приложении обратиться db.EmployySkill, но нет это таблица EmployySkill создаётся автоматически.

Подскажите как имея контекст то есть db, а значит имея и id в всех employee и id всех skill, как мне выцепить скилы, которые относятся к определённому Employee?

```
public class Employee : BaseEmployee
{
    public Employee() { }
}

public abstract class BaseEmployee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public bool Bonus { get; set; }
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; } = new List<Skill>();
    public Vacansy Vacansy { get; set; }
    public int VacansyId { get; set; }

    public BaseEmployee() { }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " " + SecondName;
    }
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();

    public Skill() { }
}

public class CompanyContext : DbContext
{
    public CompanyContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=N105124;Database=RR54;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vacansy> Vacansies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: При чём тут Linq и какие-то модели? есть связанные таблицы с данными? показывайте их CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (по 3-5 записей) и требуемый результат для таких данных. И укажите точно СУБД, включая точную версию.

Comment: СУБД SSMS 18, про таблицы я вроде уже рассказал, какие там поля, какая ещё инфа нужна? Linq при том, что это вроде как при помощи linq to sql делается, нет?

Comment: SSMS - это не СУБД, а клиентское приложение, работающее в основном с SQL Server (MS SQL).

Comment: Аааааа, ну тогда ясно

Comment: Какую именно ORM используете? Entity Framework? EF Core? Укажите точную версию. Укажите используемый язык программирования (скорее всего C#). Приведите классы-сущности (можно опустить большинство свойств).

Comment: EF Core, ага C#. Классы добавил в вопросе.

Comment: Сделайте свойство Employee.Skills виртуальным, и не присваивайте ему пустой лист. Если мне не изменяет память, после этого оно станет возвращать скилы присущие конкретному объекту Employee.

Comment: @Uranus - это в обычном EF достаточно было сделать свойство виртуальным. В EF Core чуть сложнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно подгрузить связанные данные, тогда они появятся в свойстве `Skills` класса `Employee`.

[Loading Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Энергичная загрузка:

```
var employee = context.Employees.Include(e => e.Skills).First();
```

Явная загрузка:

```
var employee = context.Employees.First();

context.Entry(employee).Collection(e => e.Skills).Load();
```

Чтобы включить ленивую загрузку придётся повозиться чуть дольше. Но она считается моветоном и не рекомендуется.

---

В обратную сторону работает аналогично. Можно получить из БД сущность Skill и подгрузить к ней связанные сущности Employee.